# Как проверить обратимость матрицы внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, матрицы, линейная-алгебра

Не могу правильно собрать все процедуры внутри класса. Есть набор данных, которые нужно зашифровать. Создаю класс, внутри которого создается матрица и на нее умножаются исходные данные:

```
class Preparer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):


def fit(self, X, y=None, random_state=None):
    if random_state:
        np.random.seed(random_state)
        
    X_d = X.shape[1]
    Z = np.random.normal(size=(X_d, X_d))
    
    
    self.Z = Z
    self.X = X
    return self


def transform(self, X, y=None):  
    return X.dot(self.Z)

X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
```

Хочу добавить внутри класса проверку этой матрицы на обратимость, сначала попробовал вот так:

```
class Preparer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):


def fit(self, X, y=None, random_state=None):
    if random_state:
        np.random.seed(random_state)
        
    X_d = X.shape[1]
    Z = np.random.normal(size=(X_d, X_d))
    
    
    self.Z = Z
    self.X = X
    return self

def check(self):
    ch = self.Z
    Z_rev = np.linalg.inv(ch)
    if np.allclose(np.dot(ch, Z_rev), np.eye(ch.shape[0])) is True:
        ans = "Correct, it's alive"
    else:
        ans = "Incorrect"
    return ans

def transform(self, X, y=None):  
    return X.dot(self.Z)

X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
print(Preparer().check())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-970f16a02444> in <module>
      1 X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
----> 2 check_m = Preparer().check()
      3 print(Preparer().check())
      4 display(X.shape, X_new.shape)

<ipython-input-48-325b53b325ec> in check(self, y)
     15 
     16     def check(self, y=None):
---> 17         ch = self.Z
     18         Z_rev = np.linalg.inv(ch)
     19         if np.allclose(np.dot(ch, Z_rev), np.eye(ch.shape[0])) is True:

AttributeError: 'Preparer' object has no attribute 'Z'
```

Затем попробовал через конструктор определить переменные:

```
class Preparer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    
    def __init__(self, Z, X):
        self.Z = Z
        self.X = X
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None, random_state=None):
        if random_state:
            np.random.seed(random_state)
            
        X_d = X.shape[1]
        self.Z = np.random.normal(size=(X_d, X_d))
        
        
        return self
    
    def check(self):
        Z_rev = np.linalg.inv(Z)
        if np.allclose(np.dot(self.Z, Z_rev), np.eye(self.Z.shape[0])) is True:
            ans = "Correct, it's alive"
        else:
            ans = "Incorrect"
        return ans
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):  
        return X.dot(self.Z)
```

В итоге ловлю вот такую ошибку:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ceee7b2c8018> in <module>
----> 1 X_new = Preparer().fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
      2 #print(Preparer().check())
      3 display(X.shape, X_new.shape)

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Z' and 'X'
```

Не могу понять, как правильно это все собрать. Просмотрел несколько статей по классам, но не смог найти какую-то подробную, там все слишком упрощенно, в реале потом воспроизвести на своем примере не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тут внутри класса все построить или может какую статью хорошую посоветуете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавайте экземпляр класса и работайте с ним. В `sklearn` насколько я помню все трансформеры именно так работают.

```
preparer = Preparer() # если есть параметры инициализации, передайте их тут
X_new = preparer.fit_transform(X, random_state=12345)
print(preparer.check())
```

Вы же просто создаёте в каждой строке новый экземпляр класса, вызывая его конструктор: `Preparer()`. Новый экземпляр класса ничего не знает о переменных предыдущего экземпляра (но знает статические переменные, что в общем-то не выход в данном случае). И в реализации класса вы путаете статические переменные и переменные экземпляра класса `self.`, разберитесь, где у вас чего, и всё заработает. Лучше без особой надобности не делать статических переменных, обычно это плохой стиль, так же как и использовать глобальные переменные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за объяснение и подсказку! Я недавно просто начал разбираться с программированием, поэтому затупил, действительно, нужно было сразу новый экземпляр создать и все

Comment: @DmitShev Такое часто бывает в программистской практике, что вроде всё сделал правильно - а не работает, какую-то деталь в упор не видно, и тут на помощь приходит этот сайт )